# C# RouteTable Configuration in .Net 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I'm trying to add a Web API controller to a legacy .Net 4.0 Web Forms application. I understand that I need to map the API routes in the Application_Start method. The problem that I'm having is that I don't have a RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute property, just a RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute property.

How do I set the routes properly in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix this was to add a reference to System.Web.Http.WebHost so I could access GlobalConfiguration.Configuration. With this I created a static class called WebApiConfig with a static Register method that takes a single parameter of type HttpConfiguration. In the Application_Start method I call the static Register method with GlobalConfiguration.Configuration as the parameter. This parameter allows me to access the MapHttpRoute property.